# Node redis doesn't like function.apply()

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, apply

I'm trying to wrap a redis client in node but I seem to be having some issues with calling node-redis functions with .apply().
This is causing issues when I tried to do it, which I was able to work around, but now async is calling its functions using .apply() as well which is now causing issues.

Below is a simplification of what I'm doing:

```
var client = redis.createClient( myOptions );
function set(){
  // do other stuff
  client.set.apply( null, arguments );
}
```

However, when I do this I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send_command' of null
    at RedisClient.(anonymous function).RedisClient.(anonymous function) (E:\sitesroot\0\node_modules\redis\lib\commands.js:45:24)
```

The code works perfectly when I pass in the arguments manually like so:

```
function set( key, value ){
  // do stuff
  client.set( key, value );
}
```

This approach won't work though for the likes of wrapping hgetall which has an unspecified number of arguments...

Any insight on what might be causing this?

Comment: Why are you passing `null` as the context? Pass the `client`!

Comment: Yep, that seems to have done it. However, when using async.apply() its internally hard-coded to use null unfortunately. Managed to get around it by using function.bind(), of course passing client as the context and its working! Now to do some reading on call(), apply() and bind() as I clearly don't fully understand them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bergi pointed out in the comment above, you need to pass the correct context when you apply.

```
client.set.apply( client, arguments );
```